# Requesting a type when sending a property in a link

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I am rewriting the project written in Javascript with Typescript.
A type is requested in the state value sent to the link component and it throws an error.
But I didn't know where to do this.

```
<S.Forgot>
      <Link to={{ pathname: "/forgot", state: { type: "merchant" } }}>
        Şifremi Unuttum
      </Link>
    </S.Forgot>
```

error

```
  Type '{ pathname: string; state: { type: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'To'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'state' does not exist in type 'Partial<Path>'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(53, 5): The expected type comes from property 'to' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LinkProps & RefAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are using `react-router-dom@6`. For the `Link` component that `state` is a top-level prop, not a property on the `to` prop. Move `state` out on its own as a prop.

Example:

```
<S.Forgot>
  <Link to="/forgot" state={{ type: "merchant" }}>
    Şifremi Unuttum
  </Link>
</S.Forgot>
```

Route/Link state is still accessed via the `location` object.

```
const { state } = useLocation();
const { type } = state || {};
```